# Is there an existing name for this button/loading animation combo?

Tags: design-patterns

Has anyone yet heard/come up with a name for this design solution? It combines a loading animation / progress bar into the button itself.

The developer refers to it as 'ladda'.

http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/

Answer (score 2):

The other reference I found to these [kind of buttons is called Loda](http://jquery-plugins.net/loda-button-buttons-with-loading-animation) . To quote the page

> Loda Button jQuery plugin that animates the button icon with CCS3 when
>   loading data from the server.
>
> The animation is created using CSS3's animation, transitions and
>   transforms, which are supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE10.

Another naming convention I found for them (with a different loading animation) is **[progress buttons](http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/)**

Comment: Although even the people who call them "progress buttons" refer back to Ladda. See here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/12/progress-button-styles/

Comment: Thanks. I think progress buttons makes sense for a design pattern name. 

I'm wondering if others agree. Again, thanks so much Mervin.